# Graphql - how to omit tables from the auto-generated graphiql

Tags: postgresql, graphql, postgraphile

Im working on postgraphile server. the stack is: nodejs, expressjs, postgraphile and knex.

My auto-generated graphiql exposes queries to tables it doesn't need to - `knex_migrations`.

following this doc: https://medium.com/make-it-heady/graphql-omit-table-from-generating-under-graphiql-postgres-smart-comments-6d3b6abec37

in the pgAdmin, I added in the properties of the `knex_migrations` table the followings:

```
@name knex_migrations
@omit create,update,delete
This is the documentation.
```

still when running the server and opening graphiql, I see queries for the migrations table.

what am I missing

Comment: You'll want to `@omit read`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely omit the table completely from your graphql schema using a smart comment, you simply need to use the `@omit` tag without any following actions. Using `@omit create,update,delete` only removes the autogenerated mutations -but does not remove read operations (usage in queries).

See docs for [`@omit`](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/smart-tags/#omit) for all available options.